How to Make the Blog Section of My Onepage HTML/Bootstrap Website Dynamic Using Sanity, Contentful, or Netlify?
I'm currently working on a one-page website built with HTML, Bootstrap, and a bit of JavaScript. I want to make the blog section dynamic so that I can easily update content without manually editing the HTML file each time.
I've tried using platforms like Sanity, Contentful, and Netlify CMS, but I couldn't get them to work as expected. I'm relatively new to JavaScript, so I'm looking for guidance on how to integrate one of these (or any other recommended platform) into my existing static site.
Here’s a summary of my situation:
Website Tech Stack: HTML, Bootstrap, a bit of JavaScript.
Goal: Make the blog section dynamic.
Platforms Attempted: Sanity, Contentful, Netlify CMS.
Skill Level: Beginner in JavaScript.
I would appreciate a step-by-step guide or any advice on how to approach this problem. If possible, please explain it in a beginner-friendly way.
Thank you in advance for your help!
I attempted to integrate Sanity, Contentful, and Netlify CMS into my one-page HTML/Bootstrap site to make the blog section dynamic. My goal was to be able to update the blog content through a CMS interface without manually changing the HTML file each time.
However, despite following various tutorials and documentation, I couldn’t get the platforms to work as expected. For example, with Contentful, I struggled to properly fetch and display the content using JavaScript. With Sanity, I had trouble setting up the schema and connecting it to my existing site. Netlify CMS seemed promising, but I couldn't figure out how to make it work with my simple HTML/Bootstrap setup.
I was expecting to be able to easily fetch and display blog posts dynamically from one of these CMS platforms. Ideally, I want a beginner-friendly solution that doesn’t require advanced JavaScript knowledge.

please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
